# Boost Graph Library: subgraph isomorphism with adjacency_matrix

Tags: c++, boost, adjacency-matrix, subgraph, isomorphism

I am using Boost 1.83 with the latest Cygwin.  The problem I'm having also occurred with Boost 1.66.

I am trying to use the Boost Graph Library isomorphism function on an adjacency_matrix:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/vf2_sub_graph_iso.hpp>
#include <iostream>

//typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS,
//                boost::vecS,
//                boost::bidirectionalS> Graph;

typedef boost::adjacency_matrix<boost::bidirectionalS> Graph;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  Graph g_small(3);

  boost::add_edge(0, 1, g_small);
  boost::add_edge(1, 2, g_small);
  boost::add_edge(2, 0, g_small);

  Graph g_large(5);

  boost::add_edge(0, 1, g_large);
  boost::add_edge(1, 2, g_large);
  boost::add_edge(2, 3, g_large);
  boost::add_edge(3, 4, g_large);
  boost::add_edge(4, 2, g_large);

  auto callback = [&](auto f, auto f_inv) {
    std::cout << "isomorphism" << std::endl;
    return true; // give us more isomorphisms if any
  };
  
  boost::vf2_subgraph_iso(g_small, g_large, callback);

  return 0;
}
```

The code compiles with an adjacency list, but with an adjacency matrix I get the following error (only first few lines shown).  It then complains about some missing functions (I assume the ones that are in the Bidirectional model but not the Directed model).

```
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp:27,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/functional/hash.hpp:6,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/unordered/unordered_set.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/unordered_set.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp:20,
                 from mwe.cc:1:
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp: In instantiation of ‘class boost::adjacency_matrix<boost::bidirectionalS>’:
mwe.cc:14:16:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp:455:5: error: static assertion failed: !(is_same< Directed, bidirectionalS >::value)
  455 |     BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(!(is_same< Directed, bidirectionalS >::value));
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp:455:5: note: ‘!(bool)boost::integral_constant<bool, true>::value’ evaluates to false
```

I thought I understood the documentation that says it should work ... am I missing something?  I can't use adjacency_list because it seems that subgraph isomorphism is waaay too slow on large adjacency list graphs.

Edit: If I change the typedef in the minimal working example I posted to

```
typedef boost::adjacency_matrix<boost::directedS> Graph;
```

I get an error that seems to say the subgraph function is expecting Bidirectional but instead it got Directed.  See excerpt below.

```
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/graph_concepts.hpp:118:1:   required from ‘static void boost::concepts::requirement<boost::concepts::failed************ Model::************>::failed() [with Model = boost::concepts::BidirectionalGraphConcept<boost::adjacency_matrix<boost::directedS> >]’
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/vf2_sub_graph_iso.hpp:931:9:   required from ‘bool boost::detail::vf2_subgraph_morphism(const GraphSmall&, const GraphLarge&, SubGraphIsoMapCallback, IndexMapSmall, IndexMapLarge, const VertexOrderSmall&, EdgeEquivalencePredicate, VertexEquivalencePredicate)
```

Comment: Open /usr/local/include/boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp in your editor of choice and go to line 455. What do you see around it?

Comment: Yes, I see a comment to the effect of "use directedS instead of bidirectionalS" and the line "    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(!(is_same< Directed, bidirectionalS >::value));".  Tried it and get a different slew of error messages which seem to be the isomorphism function objecting that the required Bidirectional concept is not satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this "puritan" restriction that you may not use AdjacencyMatrix as a (poor man's) BidirectionalGraph even if just for toying/comparison.

Turns out it's pretty easy to convince the library to "Trust Me, I Know What I'm Doing". You need a distinct graph type that you can specialize the traits for:

```
struct Graph : boost::adjacency_matrix<boost::directedS> {
    using Impl = boost::adjacency_matrix<boost::directedS>;
};
```

Now you have a type that you can lie about:

```
namespace boost {
    template <> struct graph_traits<Graph> : graph_traits<Graph::Impl> {
        struct traversal_category
            : boost::bidirectional_graph_tag
            , Graph::Impl::traversal_category {};
    };

    // O(2N)
    auto degree(Graph::vertex_descriptor u, Graph const& g) {
        return size(out_edges(u, g)) + size(in_edges(u, g));
    }
}; // namespace boost
```

That's all:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d53604db9b8f0085)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/vf2_sub_graph_iso.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct Graph : boost::adjacency_matrix<boost::directedS> {
    using Impl = boost::adjacency_matrix<boost::directedS>;
    // using Impl::Impl;
    // using Impl::operator=;
};

namespace boost {
    template <> struct graph_traits<Graph> : graph_traits<Graph::Impl> {
        struct traversal_category
            : boost::bidirectional_graph_tag
            , Graph::Impl::traversal_category {};
    };

    // O(2N)
    auto degree(Graph::vertex_descriptor u, Graph const& g) {
        return size(out_edges(u, g)) + size(in_edges(u, g));
    }
}; // namespace boost

int main() {
    Graph g_small(3);

    add_edge(0, 1, g_small);
    add_edge(1, 2, g_small);
    add_edge(2, 0, g_small);

    Graph g_large(5);

    add_edge(0, 1, g_large);
    add_edge(1, 2, g_large);
    add_edge(2, 3, g_large);
    add_edge(3, 4, g_large);
    add_edge(4, 2, g_large);

    auto callback = [&](auto f, auto /*f_inv*/) {
        std::cout << "isomorphism";
        for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g_small))) {
            std::cout << " " << v << "->" << f[v];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        return true; // give us more isomorphisms if any
    };

    vf2_subgraph_iso(g_small, g_large, callback);
}
```

Printing the output

```
isomorphism 0->2 1->3 2->4
isomorphism 0->3 1->4 2->2
isomorphism 0->4 1->2 2->3
```

### Closing Notes

YMMV: of course the performance won't be optimal, but as you said, neither will most other models. You might have your cake and eat it if you are able to pre-calculate/cache the degree for each vertex. Depending on your domain logic this may be easy to add.

Comment: In your degree function, don't you mean size(in_edges(u,g)) + size(out_edges(u,g)) ?

Comment: Yeah ... error is still in the second copy, the complete program.  :-(

Comment: @EdwardDoolittle and the Coliru link. That's what I get for trying to edit on a cell phone. Now fixed in all three spots. Interestingly, output unaffected :)

Comment: I implemented your suggestion.  As you suspected, it runs slowly: not just the degree function, but all the edge accesses are O(N).  To get speed out of this, all those functions would need to be reimplemented too.  Interestingly, the Glasgow Subgraph Solver is built on Boost Graph Library but runs about 50,000 times faster than my code.  So I've got work to do ... or I'll just keep using the GSS.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

So, after digging through the Boost Graph Library (BGL) header files, I think I have a better idea of what's happening.

Boost discourages you, or rather stops you, from using bidirectionalS with adjacency_matrix, apparently because the list in_edge, list out_edge, in_degree, and out_degree functions violate the constant time promise of BGL's bidirectional graphs.  This is extremely irritating, because adjacency_list graphs violate the constant time promise for edge access that adjacency_matrix provides, but that doesn't prevent you from using adjacency_list whenever you want and accepting whatever trade-offs result.

In addition, some functions in adjacency_matrix remain unimplemented, which is rather alarming for a 20 year old library.  BGL's developers and maintainers appear not to have done anything at except minor bug fixes for nearly 20 years.  Given all the research on graph data structures and algorithms in that time, and all the changes in C++, I would say BGL is really showing its age.  That is too bad, because I like the idea of it, and I enjoy using it (when it works).

In my application, I don't care about memory, only speed, and my large, dense graph is fixed (no changes to vertices or edges) after initial creation, so I really would like to set up a new graph type which uses both adjacency matrix and adjacency list and picks the fastest structure to respond to any query (e.g., adjacency matrix when querying the presence of a edge between two given vertices, and adjacency list when querying the out edges of a vertex).  However, it feels like you would need a PhD in abstract algebra to set up a new graph type BGL.  I exaggerate, but bottom line is, I can get up to speed with an alternative faster than I can get BGL to do what I want.

So, my solution to my problem is to use the LEMON graph library.

Comment: Erm. trying to cut through the rant here. What _specific_ operation on `adjacency_matrix` is missing that you imagine would be _added_ by using `bidirectionalS`? The way I see it  edge lookup is O(1) for the matrix regardless of the direction, and since your graph is dense, simple iteration would replace `out_edges` as well as `in_edges`?

Comment: Mmm. Re-reading the comments at the question, I _guess_ the only pain point is that, because of technical reasons (strict adherence to runtime-cost promises) the Matrix does not model BidirectionalGraph and your isomorphism search algorithm of choice requires it. Mmm Will see how hard it would be to tell BGL "I know, just do it"

Comment: I posted my answer on how to do just that. I'd be curious to learn how to do the same with LEMON. It does look more actively evolving. Cheers

Comment: @sehe LEMON is definitely fresher but lacks Bron-Kerbosch and a subgraph isomorphism finder.  I imagine I can easily implement Bron-Kerbosch or another clique finder, and implement subgraph isomorphism with somewhat more difficulty.  Now I have three ways to continue my research: your answer above, LEMON, and the Glasgow Subgraph Solver (which just reads graph files from the filesystem but that too can eventually be fixed).  Thank you again.